# How to search an Access database text field for a substring

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have looked through several pages and not been able to find what I need. What I found has gotten me something that "works" but not the way I want it to.

```
SELECT p.ProductName, p.QuantityPerUnit, s.CompanyName, c.CategoryName
FROM Products AS p, Suppliers AS s, Categories AS c
WHERE p.QuantityPerUnit LIKE "*" & [500 g] & "*" AND p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID AND p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
ORDER BY p.ProductName;
```

When I run this on the Access DB a window pops up for text to be entered. It has 500 g as the label. If I put 500 g in the text field, the query works. What I want is to be able to run the query using 500 g as the substring to find with out user interaction. I know I am close but am unsure what is incorrect.

I was able to figure this out. The problem was the "[]". I switched them to single '' and it ran displaying the expected data with out requiring user intervention.

```
WHERE p.QuantityPerUnit LIKE "*" & '500 g' & "*"
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem.

Comment: When you use [500 g], Access looks for and identifier with this name. If it cannot find it, Access prompts for user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard in Access **is** "*".  You use the percent sign in SQL Server.  Take out the brackets.

```
WHERE p.QuantityPerUnit LIKE "*500 g*" AND p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID AND p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
```

Comment: Thank you, I had found a way that worked and edited my post, then saw your reply. So I tested it and it also worked. I am going with this as it seems like better coding.